# How to force ControlSource updating (excel userforms)

Tags: vba, datetime, excel, event-handling, userform

On my Excel VBA userform there is a textbox where the users should input the date in `dd-mm-yy` format. If the input is `09-22-13`, it should be updated to `22-09-2013`. This textbox has a ControlSource property set to an address of a cell; this cell's value should become `22-09-2013`, too.

The problem with all events handlers I have tried is that the value of ControlSource gets updated before the handler is triggered, and I cannot change the value of ControlSource unless I hardcode its address (this is something I'd like to avoid).

Could you help? Thanks.

```
Private Sub TextBox_MyDate_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TextBox_MynDate.Value = Format(TextBox_MyDate.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    ' TextBox_MyDate.ControlSource.Value = TextBox_MyDate.Value does not compile
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: Realized I have forgotten to upvote you :) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here something to consider, `controlsource update` and `event order` can't be changed it seems, so you may try to add `worksheet_change` event before the `textbox event` as the former fires before `textbox event` exists..

[Reference:](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/671914-control-source-updates-in-userform.html)

- It says, *if you use ContolSource then the Textbox will refresh each time the relevant cell changes, but be aware, the reverse is true. Change a TextBox & the cell will change*

Comment: Changing the textBox value from VBA (using TextBox_MynDate.Value = line) does not seem to change the cell value, otherwise I would have had an infinite recursion I guess.

Comment: worksheet_change event seems to be the only way to avoid hardcoding the cell address, but I have ended up hardcoding it because, in my case, it is simpler.

Comment: @YuccaV to solve the infinite loop with `Sheet change event` you may set `Events to false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Private Function GetCtrlSourceStr$()
        On Error Resume Next
        GetCtrlSourceStr = wCtrl.ControlSource
   End Function
```

'
' if Form is unloaded and the values in  Sheet  FoFiCriteria changed by editing the worksheet
' the form Textboxes or Checkboxes will not have linked to these changes ..
' a Form Showing or hidden will still synchronize with its control sources
' to work when the Form is open but FoFiCriteria is not the active sheet
' these ControlSource strings need to be as  ,,   SHeetName!B14  .. FoFiCriteria!L9
' as from
'  RaAdd = ra(3, Ci).Address(False, False, , True)
 '   .ControlSource = Mid(RaAdd, InStr(RaAdd, "]") + 1)

' so editing on form should link to the range of the control source on its sheet
' so we need
'

```
Sub ReGetCtrlSources()
   For Each wCtrl In frd.Controls
        If GetCtrlSourceStr <> "" Then
       wCtrl.Value = Range(wCtrl.ControlSource).Value
    wCtrl.BackColor = Range(wCtrl.ControlSource).Interior.Color
       End If

   Next wCtrl
```

End Sub

' add to activate
      Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

```
   ReGetCtrlSources

   End Sub
```